# Object inherit from NSObject causes error Property 'self._username' not initialized at super.init call

Tags: swift, inheritance, superclass

I create UserModel object inherit from NSObject I have problem with override init() in give me error because of "Property 'self._username' not initialized at super.init call". can someone told me how to fix it ? also should I always inherit from NSObject ?

```
class UserModel:NSObject
{
    let _username:String
    let _password:String
    let _isAuthenticated:Bool
    let _isManager:Bool

    init(username:String = "",password:String = "" ,isAuthenticated:Bool = false,isManager:Bool = false)
    {
        self._username = username
        self._password = password
        self._isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated
        self._isManager = isManager
    }


    override init() {
        super.init()
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You absolutely do **not** have to always inherit from `NSObject`!

`class UserModel { ... }` is perfectly fine as well

2. The error arises because when you try to call `super.init` `self` has to be properly set up. **And** after the `init()` is finished your class members do not have any values! Both is not allowed for non-optional types.

Solution: remove the `init()` and maybe even the `NSObject` inheritance:

```
class UserModel {
    let _username : String
    let _password : String
    let _isAuthenticated : Bool
    let _isManager : Bool

    init(username : String = "", password : String = "", isAuthenticated : Bool = false, isManager : Bool = false) {
        self._username = username
        self._password = password
        self._isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated
        self._isManager = isManager
    }
}
```

Sidenote: why do your variables have a leading underscore?

Comment: it is just coding conventions  we use in our shop.we use  C++ coding conventions

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, only optional types can contain nil. You either have to initialize your username property with an empty string or use an optional type

```
let _username: String?
```

or

```
let _username: String = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `_username`, `_password`, `_isAuthenticated` and `_isManager` variables are not optional. They must have a value once the initializer is finished. Your second initializer's call to `super.init()` does not give them a value, nor does the rest (i.e. nothing) of your initializer.

So if I say: `let userModel = UserModel()`, what are the values of the variables? There are no values, but they're not optional, so there MUST be values. The compiler is pointing out this contradiction.

You don't have to inherit from NSObject, and you shouldn't unless you have a reason to need to.